# How can find the folder which contains the icon in the desktop?

Tags: desktop, icons

There is an icon in my Desktop:
[image]

I want to find the icon file.

```
ls Desktop | rg wps
wps-office-prometheus.desktop
```

List the contents in `wps-office-prometheus.desktop`:

```
cat  Desktop/wps-office-prometheus.desktop
[Desktop Entry]
Comment=Use WPS Writer to office work.
Comment[zh_CN]=使用 WPS 2019进行办公
Exec=/usr/bin/wps %F
GenericName=WPS
GenericName[zh_CN]=WPS 2019
Name=WPS 2019
Name[zh_CN]=WPS 2019
StartupNotify=false
Terminal=false
Type=Application
Categories=Office;WordProcessor;Qt;
X-DBUS-ServiceName=
X-DBUS-StartupType=
X-KDE-SubstituteUID=false
X-KDE-Username=
Icon=wps-office2019-kprometheus
InitialPreference=3
StartupWMClass=wpsoffice
```

Maybe there is a file named `wps-office2019-kprometheus` containing the wps icon,i want to find the location.

```
sudo find /usr  -name  'wps-office2019-kprometheus'
sudo find ./  -name  'wps-office2019-kprometheus'
sudo find /var  -name  'wps-office2019-kprometheus'
```

None of them can find the file,how can do then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using `'wps-office2019-kprometheus'` you should use `'wps-office2019-kprometheus*'`. You are not getting any output because the icon filename contains an *extension* (such as jpg, png,svg, etc.).

So you should run:

```bash
sudo find /usr  -name  'wps-office2019-kprometheus*'
```

Or:

```bash
find /usr/share/icons  -name  'wps-office2019-kprometheus*'
# Might not be necessary to use 'sudo' and usually the icons are under
# '/usr/share/icons' path.
```